# Merging two worksheets into one and keeping the functionality

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a calculator in Excel. It uses 2 worksheets.
How can I merge both worksheets into one and keep all formulas functional.
For example, I have formulas in first worksheet referring to the second worksheet like this: `(=Sheet2!B15+Sheet2!E27)`

Now I want to cut all cells from second sheet and paste them into first one.

How can I do this?

Comment: From what I understand, most Excel questions on SO involve programmatic involvement with Excel, rather than just how to perform a task in Excel. I suppose I could be wrong, I don't spend much time in the [excel] tag. However, this question probably fits better on [su], per [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stackexchange-site-is-best-for-ms-excel-questions) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on).

Comment: @avetarman - what happened when you tried that?  Did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you wont have any problem doing this.  Excel is generally quite good a automatically updating references for you.

For example if you cut cell `A1` into cell `B1` then a formula `=A1+A2` will be updated to `=B1+A2` for you.

So first try to just cut all the cells in `Sheet 2` and paste them to the right of you cells in `Sheet 1`.If it dose have a problem with it, my best advice would be to update the top formula cells manually and drag down the 'auto fill square' to fill the range.

Thirdly you could try this:

Assume you have `X` columns of data in sheet1.

1. In sheet2 insert at least `X` New Columns to the left of Column A.
2. Check that the formulas still work.
3. Copy and paste cells from sheet2 into sheet1.  **The cells should go exactly where they were in the previous sheet.**  (i.e. Move cell `Sheet2!X1` -> `Sheet1!X1`, this should work because of the cell you have inserted in step 1 means there is no overlap).
4. Check that the formulas still work.  (They should because they will still be referencing the old data)
5. Now find replace in formulas all `"Sheet2!"` for `"Sheet1!"`
6. Check that the formulas still work.
7. You are done :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works within the same worksheet. But I cannot bring all cells from Sheet2 to Sheet1 with automatically changing references in Sheet1. And there are a lot of cells.

Comment: Ok ill update my answer, I have another idea.

Comment: Thanks again, Robert. As I stated before, I don't want to do that manually. But it seems there is no other method (No native MS method).